# DRUPAL installation on AZURE VM

Tags: php, azure, drupal-7

I am trying to install **OPIGNO** *opigno_lms-7.x-1.20-core* on AZURE V M (Bitnami Drupal 7.31-0 in the Microsoft Azure Cloud.) but whei choose the language and go to check the requirements its show these errors :

[image]

So how to solve these 2 problems ???

Comment: Do you have the 'files' folder in sites/default/ ?? If you don't have, then create this folder and give permission like 755

Comment: Also you have some file which has name default.settings.php in sites/default folder. So you could copy this file and rename it in settings.php and then you would not have any problems in future

Comment: maybe iam trying ur advice thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1.1) Open git bash;
1.2) Go to `cd /sites/default`;
1.3) `mkdir files -m 755`;

---

2.1) Go to `cd /sites/default`;
2.2) `cp default.settings.php settings.php`;